# Sql counting distinct records and grouping the count by the record name

Tags: sql, ms-access

Thanks for taking your time to read and help me out! I appreciate it.

I have a database like so:

```
1  VISA TYPE  ISSUING NATIN
2  F1         EN
3  J1         MX
```

Im trying to make a query that only looks at the VISA TYPES F1 and J1. Only looking at those records and ignoring those that arent F1 and J1, I need to count how many are from each country. Then store the result data in a table like so below.

```
1  ISSUING NATIN  NUMBER OF STUDENTS
2  EN             5
3  MX             10
```

Here is what I was trying. Im bran new to access and MySQL. So keep that in mind.

```
SELECT Count(*) AS N
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 'ISSUEING NATN' FROM 201310)
WHERE [201310].[VISA TYPE]='F1' OR [201310].[VISA TYPE]='J1'
GROUP BY 'ISSUING NATIN';
```

UPDATE: Well I got this baffiling problem fixed... how? Dont ask me... looks almost the same as eggy's.

```
SELECT
  [ISSUED NATION],
  COUNT(*)
  FROM
    201310
  GROUP BY
  [ISSUED NATION];
```

Right now im getting a syntax error with GROUP BY ISSUING NATIN, but I think I need to change some other things aswell. Any insight? Thank you!

EDIT: Fixed the issuing natin syntax error but its not working correctly!

Comment: Why is this question tagged [tag:mysql] and [tag:ms-access]?  Which are you using (the syntax suggests ms-access)?

Comment: @eggyal Obviously using ms-access to access MySQL

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: Can't tell whether that's sarcastic!  It certainly wasn't a scenario I had considered.. is it even possible?

Comment: Yes that is what I am doing eggy.

Comment: @TheNodeCommode: You're accessing MySQL (an open source RDBMS product now developed by the Oracle corporation, which has nothing at all to do with Microsoft) through MS Access (a database management product from Microsoft that often ships with their Office productivity suite)?  Are you *sure*?  How (and more importantly, **why**) do you have such a setup?

Comment: Its SQL not MySql. I see what you mean now. Yes I tagged it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT   [ISSUING NATIN], COUNT(*)
FROM     [201310]
WHERE    [VISA TYPE] IN ('F1', 'J1')
GROUP BY [ISSUING NATIN]
```

Comment: Hmm. Looks nice, but im getting an input prompt for ISSUING NATIN params? I tried [201310].[ISSUING NATIN], but no go. Is that input supposed to be the country name? Cause that didnt work either. Thanks for the help and explanation!

Comment: Still cant get it working :\

Comment: I don't really know MS Access well enough to advise.  Sorry.

Comment: eggyal used `[ISSUING NATIN]`, which is the name you first gave us. His suggested query did not work. In your working version, you used a different field name: `[ISSUING NATION]`

Comment: Yeah, whoever named the DB fields spelled ISSUING wrong and NATION obviously abbreviated. So in the end I changed the field name, that is why they are not the same. But that wasnt the problem. Thx though!